# How to register Middelware in laravel package

Tags: php, laravel

I create a laravel package and i want use middleware in this package but when register middleware in service provider and use to route , i see a problem.

this is my code in my service provider :

```
$router = $this->app['router'];
    $router->middleware('checkRoles', Ilbeygi\UserRole\Middlewares\CheckRole::class);
```

route :

```
Route::get('permission','MyController@showRole')->middleware('checkRoles');
```

error :

```
`ReflectionException (-1)
 Class checkRoles does not exist`
```

Please help me ...

laravel version : 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middleware is registered in

```
.
+-- app
|   +-- Http
|       +-- Kernel.php
```

In this Kernel Class you find the `$routeMiddleware` which is a array off registered Middleware Classes. Just add yours:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'checkRoles' => \Ilbeygi\UserRole\Middlewares\CheckRole::class,
```

One remark: If you Service Provider in not registers in your App, it is not available. You can register a service provider in:

```
.
+-- config
|   +-- app.php
```

There you have the `'providers'` list, just add your Service Provider Class.